# Python double-asterisk ** power operator behaving unexpectedly

Tags: python

I've written a function to replace scipy.interp1d by approximating the relationship between two variables (elev and MaxQ) in order to speed up my code. The equation is a fourth order polynomial. I would like the function to be able to compute Q values for single inputs and for 1D array inputs. The function is shown below.

```
def CalculateMaxFlow(elev):
    size=np.shape(elev)
    if size==():
        if (elev>367.8): #minimum elev for flow             
            return -0.00028194553726719*elev**4+0.284027992763652*elev**3-80.3765236558431*elev**2+1900880.72298153
        else: return 0
    else:
        MaxQ=np.zeros(np.shape(elev)[0])
        for i in range(np.shape(elev)[0]):
            if (elev[i]>367.8): #4th order polynomial. Not exact but okay for speeding up code              
                MaxQ[i]= -0.00028194553726719*((elev[i])**4)+0.284027992763652*((elev[i])**3)-80.3765236558431*((elev[i])**2)+1900880.72298153
            else: MaxQ[i]= 0               
        return MaxQ

elev1=380
elev5a=380+np.zeros(5)
elev5b=np.asarray([380,380,380,380,380])

Q1=CalculateMaxFlow(elev1)
print("Q1:"+ str(Q1))
Q2=CalculateMaxFlow(elev5a)
print("Q2:"+str(Q2))
Q3=CalculateMaxFlow(elev5b)
print("Q3:"+str(Q3))
```

The answers are as follows:

```
Q1:746.828053304
Q2:[ 746.8280533  746.8280533  746.8280533  746.8280533  746.8280533]
Q3:[ 6055481.13713196  6055481.13713196  6055481.13713196  6055481.13713196 6055481.13713196]
```

Q1 and Q2 give me the answer I expect. For some reason, Q3 does not. I'm wondering why this is. The only difference I can see in my console between eleva and elevb is that a is a float64 and b is an int32. Why would this change the result of the equation? Why then, does the result for Q1 (which is an int) also work as expected?

Comment: why not converting `(elev[i])**2` to `elev[i]*elev[i]` and square that again to replace `(elev[i])**4` ? that could speed up computations even more.

Comment: I get the desired results on all three cases.  Perhaps it's because I'm on Intel64 architecture?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre for efficiency and reliability commonly all `**` are converted to `*` as part of [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) (e.g. in [`numpy.polyval()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html)).

Comment: @GeoMatt22 okay but still: OP is using power of 2 AND power of 4 of the same number, so it would be logical to compute power of 4 by squaring the already computed power of 2 instead.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre not disagreeing :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Any way of speeding this up is very helpful. I am actually trying to jit the function. It works but doesn't seem to improve speed, and njit gives the error: Unknown attribute 'shape' of type Module(<module 'numpy' from 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py'>). Any idea as to why or what a workaround might be for np.shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Q3, `elev[i]` is a `numpy.int32` instance, and `elev[i]**4` overflows. With Q1, `elev` is a Python int, and `elev**4` uses arbitrary-precision arithmetic.